# Why do other XCTestCase functions run when I start one test?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xctestcase

I must be missing something really simple here, so please forgive me.

All I want is to run one of the `func`s in my `XCTestCase` class.  I do this by clicking the round start button immediately left from the `func testXyx()`.

But when I did this the debugger stops and showed it was executing another test.

Even when I made the test I wish to run an empty function, the other test is still run.

How can I run one and only one test (without other tests running first)?

Comment: I faced the same issue... I think it could be a bug from the Xcode!